# How can I use SSH as a domain controller?

Tags: ssh, samba, gdm, remote-login

I would like to use SSH as a domain controller instead of samba as the lab is only running 8 Ubuntu computers and 1 Ubuntu server. Is there a way to get Ubuntu to do this at GDM or after a user logs in and the desktop mount the remote home folder?

I thought I saw on the beta release of Ubuntu 20.04 at the GDM settings there was an option to log into ssh but it is no longer there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " SSH as a domain controller" SSH is a tool to connect to a server. Not a replacement for a domain controller. The way to do this is through winbind (=samba) (and you simulate a Windows NT4-style domain controller) and can then use `ssh {domainuser} {host}`to connect.

Comment: I have read somewhere (cant find it now)that you can use pam to authenticate users on the desktop using ssh..isn't that like samba?

Comment: That is more like 2FA (two factor auth) and not a domain controlleer. You can do that by installing `google-authenticator`. Have a read here: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/two-factor-authentication-ssh-key-ubuntu and see if that is what you can use for this?